# What are the common usages of tagging something else than a commit?

Tags: git, tagging

[Git-tag](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-tag.html) documentation states that a tag should target a commit. So does the [git book](http://book.git-scm.com/3_git_tag.html).

However, the [tests](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/t/t7004-tag.sh#L997) show that **one tag can as well target a tree, a blob or even another tag**.

Have you ever leveraged this feature? Are there some development workflows that benefit from being able to directly tag something else than a commit? Do you know any tools that rely on this git ability?

**EDIT:**

I've just found an old post on [365Git](http://365git.tumblr.com/post/497500602/git-objects-the-tag) by [@abizern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41116) which raises the same question:

> You can create tag objects for more
>   than just commits, you can tag blobs
>   and trees as well, just by passing in
>   the sha of the blob or the tree. Why
>   anyone would want to do this is beyond
>   me. It isn’t as if you can check out a
>   single file based on a tagged blob,
>   although you could reference it’s
>   contents. Maybe it can be used to
>   cryptographically sign a file or a
>   tree as coming from a particular
>   source so verify it’s integrity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a general point of view, sometime, your developpers have more than one feature in a commit : if you want to pull one without pulling the other in your tag, you can't tag on a commit, but you have to do somehow what CVS is doing : tagging each file. Can be pretty useful when prototyping